# Best way to open a mysql connection in Express 4

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

So I've installed node-mysql and I'm running on express 4. I'm brand new to express and want to learn best practicies for database connections. I currently have

**app.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); //set up mysql here

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var work = require('./routes/work');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/work', work); //send the mysql var to work..?
app.use(mysql, work);
```

As you can see I have mysql set up in app.js, how would I send this variable to work.js. I've tried:

```
app.use(mysql, work);
```

But I get an error saying mysql is undefined when I access it in my work.js file.

**Edit:**
I've added `var mysql = require('mysql'); //set up mysql here` to my work.js page and it's working fine, should i remove it from app.js? What's the best practice for this? I wouldn't want to open a new connection to the database each time I want to query it on different pages right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mysql variable in a other file like that (example with the users route):

app.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); //set up mysql here

var users = require('./routes/users')(mysql);

var app = express();
```

users.js:

```
exports = module.exports = function (mysql) {

   console.log(mysql);

   // do what you have to do with the mysql variable

}
```